# Query to pull data from column based off max value of second column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has [Order], [Yield], [Scrap], [OpAc] columns. I need to pull the yield based on the max value of [OpAc].

| Order | Yield | Scrap | OpAc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 140 | 0 | 10 |
| 1234 | 140 | 0 | 20 |
| 1234 | 130 | 10 | 30 |
| 1234 | 130 | 0 | 40 |
| 1234 | 125 | 5 | 50 |
| 1234 | 110 | 15 | 60 |
| 1235 | 140 | 0 | 10 |
| 1235 | 138 | 2 | 20 |
| 1235 | 138 | 0 | 30 |
| 1235 | 138 | 0 | 40 |
| 1235 | 138 | 0 | 50 |
| 1235 | 137 | 1 | 60 |
| 1235 | 137 | 0 | 70 |

Expected Results

| Order | Yield |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 110 |
| 1235 | 137 |

The query that I have tried is

```
select [Order], [Yield], MAX([OpAc]) as Max_OpAc
from SCRAP
GROUP BY [Order], [Yield]
order by [order]
```

This produces

| Order | Yield | Max_OpAc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 110 | 60 |
| 1234 | 125 | 50 |
| 1234 | 130 | 40 |
| 1234 | 140 | 20 |
| 1235 | 137 | 70 |
| 1235 | 138 | 50 |
| 1235 | 140 | 10 |

I've tried setting up some CTE queries to break it down into separate functions but I keep getting caught at this step.

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY [Order],[OpAc]) AS RN , * 
    FROM SAP_SCRAP
),
```

This proved to be redundant due to the fact that the [OpAc] field is sequential for each step.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it!

```
WITH Orders_By_OpAc_Desc AS (
    SELECT
        [Order],
        [Yield].
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY OpAc DESC) AS [rn],
    FROM
        SCRAP
)

SELECT [Order],
       [Yield]
FROM
    Orders_By_OpAc_Desc
WHERE
    rn = 1
```

The trick here is `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY OpAc DESC) AS [rn]`. It might be confusing to understand in SQL, but when expressed in words it's a bit clearer.

This statement takes each group of rows with the same `Order` value (`PARTITION BY [Order]`), orders each group by `OpAc` in descending order so that the higher `OpAc` values end up "on top" of the group (`ORDER BY OpAc DESC`), and numbers each row in the group "top" to "bottom", starting with 1 (`ROW_NUMBER()`).

Meaning, each row with this number set to `1` has the highest `OpAc` value for the `OrderId`.

Wrap that into a CTE and then select just the rows with this number (`rn`) set to `1`. Voi-la.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want the `OVER (PARTITION BY)` but `MAX()` is also an option here. You want something like:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t3.* 
        , MAX(OpAc) OVER (PARTITION BY  [Order]) max1
    FROM
    SCRAP t3
) a
WHERE
a.Max1 = a.OpAc
```

for `MAX()`

Depending on your SQL Server edition, version, and query needs, you may be able to use `FIRST_VALUE()` as well:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    t3.[Order],
    FIRST_VALUE(Yield) OVER(PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY OpAc DESC) Yield
FROM
SCRAP t3
```

Comment: I would want to point out that the suggested answer (both of them actually) are often significantly less performant than the `ROW_NUMBER` approach proposed by other answers.

Comment: Thank you, worked the first time.

Comment: That's a good point, thought since the OP had first been looking at `MAX()`  I did want to include the ability. `FIRST_VALUE` can have some merit if you need to work with more than one partition/order by within a single query and is good to keep in mind if you find yourself creating multiple `ROW_NUMBER() == 1` subqueries

Comment: I thought about this some more. Depending on the database architecture and other server features for execution plan generation may affect this, too. For example, I created a sample with the assumption of a table clustered index on an identity column, and a nonclustered index on Order. In this case, `a.Max1 = a.OpAc` had a better execution plan relative percentage 38% to 62% against `ROW_NUMBER`.

We also had not asked david, if the design allows duplicate "max" values of OpAc. Which `MAX()` would return all of, and `ROW_NUMBER()` approaches could swap for `RANK()` to get multiple `1`'s

Answer (score 0):

You were so close. Just missing an `ORDER BY OpAc DESC` in your `ROW_NUMBER` function.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7e4b23b/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  [Order] int null
  , Yield int null
  , Scrap int null
  , OpAc int null
);

INSERT INTO orders ([Order], Yield, Scrap, OpAc)
VALUES (1234,140,0,10)
  , (1234,140,0,20)
  , (1234,130,10,30)
  , (1234,130,0,40)
  , (1234,125,5,50)
  , (1234,110,15,60)
  , (1235,140,0,10)
  , (1235,138,2,20)
  , (1235,138,0,30)
  , (1235,138,0,40)
  , (1235,138,0,50)
  , (1235,137,1,60)
  , (1235,137,0,70)
 ;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
  SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY OpAc DESC) as row_num
  FROM orders
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE1 as c
WHERE c.row_num = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7e4b23b/2/0)**:

```
| Order | Yield | Scrap | OpAc | row_num |
|-------|-------|-------|------|---------|
|  1234 |   110 |    15 |   60 |       1 |
|  1235 |   137 |     0 |   70 |       1 |
```